# Live Stream over network

Tags: python, android, linux, streaming, live

I'm new here and hoping to get some help. I'm trying to set up a live stream over the network. One of my devices runs on Linux, while the other is an Android device with Lollipop version 5. I'm thinking of using RTP, but I'm not sure how to open the socket on the Android device. Any suggestions for multimedia protocols would be fantastic, as I need to stream video and data control one way and audio both ways. Thanks a lot for your assistance!
NOTE : I will use python script on sender side (on linux)

Tell now I don't try any thing on Android device, still searching

Comment: What's the problem in my question?